# use httpclient to send request over ip is slow

Tags: connection, ip, hosts

Now, i come with a strange question. I send http request with httpclient. In the request, when i use domain name, like dynamic.12306.cn, or i use ip address and put the ip information in windows/system32/driver/ext/hosts like `122.227.2.27 dynamic.12306.cn`, the request is quick to return. But if i only use the ip and don't put any info in to hosts, it is very slow.

The the two above, I will show example below:

Case 1. The speed is fast. The request url is https://dynamic.12306.cn/otsweb/main.jsp
or The request url is `https://122.227.2.27/otsweb/main.jsp` and put the `122.227.2.27  dynamic.12306.cn` into hosts,

Case 2. The speed is slow. The request url is `https://122.227.2.27/otsweb/main.jsp` an don't put any info into hosts.

I open the debug mode of httpclient, and i find when i use the method of case 2, it is very slow to connect to server.

The logs:

> 2013/03/17 10:19:10:665 CST [DEBUG] BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {s}->`https://122.227.2.27`
>
> 2013/03/17 10:19:11:234 CST [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to `122.227.2.27:443`
>
> 2013/03/17 10:19:20:796 CST [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match

it will cost several seconds to connect server.

But if i use the method of case 1.
The logs:

> 2013/03/17 10:30:13:876 CST [DEBUG] BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {s}->https://dynamic.12306.cn
>
> 2013/03/17 10:30:14:403 CST [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to dynamic.12306.cn:443
>
> 2013/03/17 10:30:14:499 CST [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match

it is fast to connect server.

Comment: What software are you using to connect to the server? Does it perhaps try to resolve `122.227.2.27` as a DNS name (and failing) first?

Comment: If i use ip in the request, it still needs to be resolved in DNS? And If I put the 122.227.2.27 dynamic.12306.cn in hosts, no matter what ip for domain used in request, it's fast.

Comment: That's why I'm asking about the software. Perhaps a `tcpdump` will tell you if it's doing a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

try listen to DNS query when you r doing the request. I got the same issue, which turned out the hosting website appended a hostname right after the ip.